# User is supposed to login and be redirected, doesnt redirect

Tags: php, redirect, authentication

I have this code. When a user logs in it is supposed to redirect them to members.php. Instead of redirecting them it shows a blank white page but stays on login.php.

Can anyone help?
Here is the code:

```
<?php 
 mysql_connect("xx", "xx", "xx") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("xx") or die(mysql_error()); 

 if(isset($_COOKIE['ID_my_site']))
 { 
    $username = $_COOKIE['ID_my_site']; 
    $pass = $_COOKIE['Key_my_site'];
    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'")or die(mysql_error());
    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check ))  
    {
        if ($pass != $info['password']) 
        {
        }
        else
        {
            header("Location: members.php");
        }
    }
 }

 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // if form has been submitted
    if(!$_POST['username'] || !$_POST['pass']) {
        die('You did not fill in a required field.');
    }
    if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $_POST['email'] = addslashes($_POST['email']);
    }
    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$_POST['username']."'")or die(mysql_error());
    $check2 = mysql_num_rows($check);
    if ($check2 == 0) {
        die('That user does not exist in our database. <a href=add.php>Click Here to Register</a>');
    }

    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check ))  
    {
        $_POST['pass'] = stripslashes($_POST['pass']);
        $info['password'] = stripslashes($info['password']);
        $_POST['pass'] = md5($_POST['pass']);
        if ($_POST['pass'] != $info['password']) {
            die('Incorrect password, please try again.');
        }
        else 
        { 
            $_POST['username'] = stripslashes($_POST['username']); 
            $hour = time() + 3600; 
            setcookie(ID_my_site, $_POST['username'], $hour); 
            setcookie(Key_my_site, $_POST['pass'], $hour);   
            //then redirect them to the members area 
            header("Location: members.php"); 
        } 
    } 
} 
else 
{    
?> 
 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post"> 
 <table border="0">
 <tr><td colspan=2><h1>Login</h1></td></tr>
 <tr><td>Username:</td><td> 
 <input type="text" name="username" maxlength="40"> 
 </td></tr> 
 <tr><td>Password:</td><td> 
 <input type="password" name="pass" maxlength="50"> 
 </td></tr> 
 <tr><td colspan="2" align="right"> 
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"> 
 </td></tr> 
 </table> 
 </form> 
 <?php 
 } 
 ?>
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant code here so that it is preserved for future visitors to SO? Are you seeing any errors in the log? PSA: Please quit using `mysql_` functions. *They are deprecated.* Please convert to `mysqli_` or `PDO`.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Okay i did that

Comment: I highly suggest you find a better method for doing a login. Your code uses deprecated functions and the use of MD5, which is old (*circa 1992*) and considered broken. Don't waste your time with this. You will use up less time Googling a secure method and configuring it, rather than patching this up.

Comment: Use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Plus,  [**use `mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Answer (score 0):

A good practice is to `die();` for the script to terminate and send the `Location` header to the client, on the condition that nothing has already been sent to the client.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

When setting headers it is best to always use output buffering.

```
ob_start();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

```
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check ))  
{
    if ($pass != $info['password']) 
    {
    }
    else
    {
        header("Location: members.php");
        die();
    }
}
```

To sure there is no whitespace before or after your code, it is good practice to exclude the last `?>` since that will make PHP ignore trailing whitespace.

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.
>   It is a very common error to read code with include, or require,
>   functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty
>   lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem
>   exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

Comment: You need to die(); - That's just funny :)

Comment: @lee In the game of PHP you either win or you die(); :)

Comment: Sorry, this is wrong, you don't "need" to use die() after a header command. It's just a good practice in case the header could not be sent

Comment: @YannSagon That is true, I tried to be brief. I will update that